# How to intercept and add to header auth_token for each request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, backbone.js, access-token

I'm new in jQuery Mobile and Backbone.js and trying to create a mobile application on the client-side - with API based on django rest framework.

When i POST my username&password to my api, ill get `{token: "<mytoken>"}`, which I have to intercept and added to header `"Authorization: Token <mytoken>"` in each future request on my application. How i can do this?

I have read
[Good idea to use REST token authentication for AJAX web apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170343/good-idea-to-use-rest-token-authentication-for-ajax-web-apps) and 
[How use token authentication with Rails, Devise and Backbone.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785079/how-use-token-authentication-with-rails-devise-and-backbone-js) , but i still bad understand how to integrate it into my authorization.

Does anyone can helps me with this? Thanks!

`my login view:`

```
var LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({
events: {
  "click #login": "login",
},

initialize: function () {
  this.template = $.tpl['login-form'];
},

render: function (eventName) {
  $(this.el).html(this.template());
  this.username = $("#username", this.el);
  this.password = $("#password", this.el);
  return this;
},

login: function () {
  console.log('entered');
  if (!this.username.val() || !this.password.val()) {
    return false;
  }

  var user = new User({
    username : this.username.val(),
    password : this.password.val(),
  });

  user.save({}, {success: function() {
    window.workspace.navigate('#transaction/list', { trigger: true });
    return true;
  }});

  return false;

 }
 });
```

`user model:`

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
      username: "",
      password: ""
  },
  url:"http://localhost/rest2/api-token-auth/"
 });
```

`template:`

```
  <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
    <input id="username" name="username" type="text" placeholder="username"/>
  </div>
  <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
    <input name="password" id="password" type="text" placeholder="password"/></input>
  </div>


  <a name="login" id="login" data-role="button">login</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override Backbone.sync like this. Each request with Backbone goes through Backbone.sync

```
Backbone._sync = Backbone.sync
Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
    options = $.extend({
        // In case the request is cross domain, keep these next 4 lines
        crossDomain: true
        , xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        }
        // Add the token to the request header
        , beforeSend: function(xhr){
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Token ' + token);
        }
    }, options);

    return Backbone._sync(method, model, options);
}
```

You could store the token in localStorage when you post the credentials. I noticed i had to add a short timeout before redirecting in order for the script to have time store the token in localstorage.

```
user.save({}, {success: function(model, response) {
    localStorage.setItem('access_token', response.token)
    setTimeout(function(){
          window.workspace.navigate('#transaction/list', { trigger: true}); }
    , 100);
    return true;
}});
```

and fetch it from there with

```
, beforeSend: function(xhr){
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Token ' + localStorage.access_token);
}
```

in order to allow the user to remained logged in when opening a new browser window or tab.

Comment: yeah! thanks, but i have a little question, how do intercept my token? Your decision works only if i put my token to `'Authorization', 'Token ' + token`. Or i missed something somewhere?

Comment: I've added an explanation about how to store the token when you receive it, if that's what you mean :)